# No provisioning profiles with a valid signing

Tags: xcode, certificate, apple-push-notifications

I am an ios developer. I am part of a team with the Team Admin role. I was updated to that role this morning.

I will describe my steps to create certificates and profiles:

1. I create an App ID called: com.bla.bla.test (the ID) and I edit to enable push notifications, setting a new certificate for using it.
2. I create a  certificate for push notification app com.bla.bla.test (it has the type: APNs Development iOS in Certificates Tab) Now development push notifications is enabled(green) while distribution is configurable (orange)
3. I go to provisioning profiles and I add a new one for development. I take the App ID created before and I use my certificate (My name (iOS Development)) from just 4 (other 3 members and me, all as iOS Development). After I choose phones from my team (all of them).

I download certificate of my new app, and provisioning profile. I double click them in finder and I try to configure app in xcode for using them. But always I get the same error: No provisioning profile...

I guess that the bundle Identifier in Target: NameOfProject should match with my app ID, ok it does. In team appears my team name with my user inside (): NameOfTeam(mymail@bla.com).
In Info tab, bundle identifier is the same as General tab.

In build settings tab, I guess I should set in Code Signing Identity my user, but I also can set the push profile created for this app. I just can set my user in Debug and Any SDK lines. Not the others. I leave them in IPhone Developer.

In provisioning profile I set the provisioning profile created.

In project, I can set my certificate in all lines: Code Signing Identity, debug, ios 7.0 SDK, Release and IOS 7.0 SDK

Also I can use provisioning profile in all lines of provisioning profile block.

But I still get the same error. I click on fix Issue button from xcode promt window but it can't do anything. After a while, the same window appears.

In organizer, my provisioning profile appears with a yellow icon saying: valid signing identity not found.

Any idea? I am reading a lot, deleting a recreating certificates again since last 4 days and nothing gets better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the exact same message today. And I haven't even touched my provisioning profiles for some time.

To check the settings I edited the provisioning profile (on Apple developer center). I noticed that "select all" was checked under Certificates, but the individual certificate (I only have one) was not checked. I made sure the certificate was checked, and downloaded the profile again.

I also had to make sure that my project used the new profile in Build Settings.

That fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Yes, I solved long time ago. I also had to connect iphone to itunes to synchronize and download new profiles from organizer.

Comment: Yep, googled and found your post when the error occurred. Figured you had fixed it, but thought it was nice to leave a comment for the next visitor ;)

Comment: I forgot to come back and post a solution. so thanks for doing it ;)